# jQuery - If this or this get failed inputs name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the name of the of the input that failed this tiny validation like so:

```
 var username = jQuery("#modlgn-username").val();
 var password = jQuery("#modlgn-passwd").val();

  if(username < 2 || password < 2){
   jQuery('.login-error').html('Incorrect'+jQuery(this).attr("name")).slideDown(300);
  }else{
   sendLogin(datasubmit);
  }
```

But I am so far I've been very unsuccessful. Is this at all possible?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry my question seems to be unclear, I know how to validate the fields that parts fine.. I am struggling with:

```
jQuery(this).attr("name");
```

It does not return the failed inputs name. How would i get the failed inputs name?

Comment: I do not understand your if statement

Comment: Yes, what validation conditions do you want to check?

Comment: well basically I'm just trying to check that the two fields are at least more then 2chars..

Comment: Ive updated the question, to show what I'm validating

Comment: how are you delegating this function? $('form').on('submit',function(){...});  please show the whole function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per comment

```
 I'm just trying to check that the two fields are at least more then 2chars.
```

You need to use `length` property

```
  if(username.length < 2 || password.length < 2){
   jQuery('.login-error').html('Incorrect'+jQuery(this).attr("name")).slideDown(300);
  }else{
   sendLogin(datasubmit);
  }
```

### EDIT

It is very difficult to analyse `this` in the code fragment `jQuery(this).attr("name");` without seeing complete code.

You can this, As per comment given below

```
var username = jQuery("#modlgn-username").val();
var password = jQuery("#modlgn-passwd").val();

if(username < 2 ){
    jQuery('.login-error').html('Incorrect' + jQuery("#modlgn-username").attr("name")).slideDown(300);
}else if(password < 2){
    jQuery('.login-error').html('Incorrect' + jQuery("#modlgn-passwd").attr("name")).slideDown(300);
}
else{
    sendLogin(datasubmit);
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to get the name of the of the input that failed this tiny validation" - thank you but this is the actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Assumed you want to validate input length.

```
 var username = jQuery("#modlgn-username").val();
 var password = jQuery("#modlgn-passwd").val();

 if(username.length < 2 || password.length < 2){
    jQuery('.login-error').html('Incorrect'+jQuery(this).attr("name")).slideDown(300);
    return false;
  }else{
    sendLogin(datasubmit);
 }
```